# Why should I indicate System.Web before HttpContext.Current?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

## Context

I'm in a controller.

I use the namespace `System.Web` :

```
using System.Web;
```

When I call `HttpContext.Current`, VS alerts me that `Current` isn't defined in `HttpContextBase` :

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["currentUser"];
```

If I indicate `System.Web` before `HttpContext.Current`, it works :

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["currentUser"];
```

## Question

Why should I indicate `System.Web` before `HttpContext.Current`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are in the context of a controller. A controller has a property called `HttpContext` of the type `HttpContextBase`. The instance of this property is a wrapper around the current `HttpContext`, this means you don't have to call `HttpContext.Current` as this already is available in the controller using the property.

You could do it like this instead (as long as you are in a controller):

```
HttpContext.Session["currentUser"];
```

Answer (score 3):

you have namespace conflict, use this:

`using HttpContext = System.Web.HttpContext;`

Comment: `HttpContext` is defined in another namespace?

Comment: Read my comment. HttpContext is a property of Controller

Comment: @GG., yeah, Raman have explained the more popular in own answer

Answer (score 2):

Controller class contains HttpContext property of type HttpContextBase, that is why such an ambiguity takes place

```
public HttpContextBase HttpContext { get; }
```

That is why you should use full qulaified name or alias

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.httpcontext.aspx

Comment: Or just skip Current in your expression as this HttpContext instance is already one you need